# Я по-быстрому поеду скоро, т. е. после того(,) как начнётся суперсклон

Tags: запятые

С запятой?

> Я по-быстрому поеду скоро, т. е. после того(,) как начнётся суперсклон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что правильно так:

(1) *Я по-быстрому поеду **скОро,** **т. е. пОсле того**, // как начнётся суперсклон.*

(2) *Я **по-бЫстрому** поеду скоро, **т. е. после того / как** начнётся суперсклОн.*

**Пояснение**

1. Это **сложная** конструкция: пояснительный союз ***ТО ЕСТЬ*** + придаточное предложение.

Решение **осложняется** наличием сходных по смыслу наречий ***скоро*** и **по-быстрому** в первой части.

Обычные варианты:

*Я по-быстрому поеду **после того, как** начнётся суперсклон.*

*Я по-быстрому поеду, **после того как** начнётся суперсклон.*

2. Придаточное **на втором месте,** поэтому смысл предложения зависит от **ГЛАВНОГО предложения**, а именно от расстановки  нем **логических** ударений. И именно здесь автор делает свой **ВЫБОР** (скоро поеду или по-быстрому поеду). Постановка **ПАУЗ** вторична по отношению к ударениям.
3. **В первом** варианте выделяем "**поеду скОро, то есть пОсле того, как".** Придаточное логически выделено: союз  ***ТО ЕСТЬ*** относится **к местоименной части.**

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

И это было бы **ЕДИНСТВЕННЫМ** решением, если бы в первой части не было наречия **по-быстрому**). Не так уж **велики** авторские возможности для свободной расстановки пауз и ударений, не стоит их преувеличивать и на этом **основывать** выбор знаков.

**Семантику и грамматику** предложения надо учитывать в **первую** очередь, **ИНТОНАЦИОННЫЙ анализ** используется **для коррекции** решения, но не является ведущим. Это **форма,** которая зависит от содержания.
Нужно помнить о трех принципах пунктуации, но начинать надо с **грамматики и смысла**, а не ударения сразу ставить.

4. **Во втором** варианте выделяем "**по-бЫстрому поеду, то есть после того как"**. Придаточное поясняет все главное предложение, союз не расчленяется. Ударение ставится в конце придаточного, местоименная часть  ударением не выделяется.

Answer (score 0):

*После того как* — сложный союз. Запятая может как ставиться, так и нет.

*Я по-быстрому поеду скоро, т. е. после того как начн**ё**тся суперскл**о**н* — на месте указанной вами запятой нет паузы, ударение только на последних словах предложения;

*Я по-быстрому поеду скоро, т. е. после тог**о**, как начн**ё**тся суперскл**о**н* — а вот тут автор ставит паузу перед второй частью союза (*как*) и ставит ударение на первую его часть (*после тог**о***), выделяя ее интонацией, ставя на нее логическое ударение.

По [2-му пункту](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138) автор сам может выбрать, ставить запятую между частями союза или нет, в зависимости от интонации.

Comment: По пункту 2 местоименная часть входит или не входит в главное предложение, а здесь в обоих вариантах не входит. Нестандартный синтаксис. Как объяснить по правилам и по грамматике (без интонации)?